# Adjusting a different touch spots on object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm developing a game using the Unity3d game engine and there is a little problem that I need help with

The problem is basically, I want to create multiple touch spots on my object for example if I touch on the bottom of the object it does something.

But if I touch on the top of the object it should do something different. How can I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome! At StackOverflow we request specific questions and some evidence of effort on behalf of the poster.  What have you tried so far? Do you have any part-working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: Create different collisions boxes or spheres etc.. on the object.